# Intellij does not detect mariadb connector included in build.gradle

Tags: intellij-idea

My sql queries are highlighted and when I hover over them, IntelliJ prompts me to configure data source. I select MariaDB from the drivers list. This is what I see:
[image]

The problem is I have MariaDB connector/j 2.5.3. I have 
`implementation 'org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:2.5.3'` in the dependencies of my build.gradle and can use it in code.

Is there any way for IntelliJ to detect the driver and use it other than to add my own driver and giving the path of the driver jars (because of which I lose MariaDB SQL completion and get the generic instead).

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own custom driver. Click on the button highlighted in the below picture and select the location of the jar.
[image]